# Automating 'Merge Selected Features' in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, merge

In QGIS can I create a model in the Graphical Modeler that does the equivalent of the following manual steps if I were just using menus/toolbars? If I can't via the Modeler is there another way in QGIS or even a different tool like GDAL tools to automate this?

1. [Assume I've opened a shapefile/layer]
2. Toggle Editing on
3. Edit->Select->Select All Features
4. Edit->Edit Geometry->Merge Selected Features
5. Take attributes from first feature

I have a large number of shapefiles. Each one contains up to thousands of features, each a vertical slice of the whole as shown in the first image below. I'd like to automate the above steps so I can convert each shapefile such that it contains a single feature combining all the original features as shown in the second image. All the features within a shapefile have the same attributes. I do not want to combine shapefiles, simply combine the features within a shapefile.

[image: sample vertical features]
[image: merged features]

Comment: Try using Dissolve from the processing toolbox and run as batch process.

Comment: Or [merge](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#qgismergevectorlayers) all shapefiles then [aggregate](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgisaggregate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are merging all the features of your shapefiles, you can use [Dissolve](https://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vector_geometry_tools/dissolve.html) instead + a for loop with PyQGIS to dissolve all your shapefiles.

```py
import glob, os, processing
    
#Put here the paths of your input and output folders   
inputFolder = r"C:\\Users\\_M92\\Desktop\\Jeff_S\\OriginalShapefiles"
outputFolder = r"C:\\Users\\_M92\\Desktop\\Jeff_S\\DissolvedShapefiles\\"
    
os.chdir(inputFolder)
    
for lyr in glob.glob("*.shp"):
    processing.run("native:dissolve", {'INPUT':lyr, 'OUTPUT': outputFolder + 'Dissolved_' + lyr})
    iface.addVectorLayer(outputFolder + 'Dissolved_' + lyr, 'Dissolved_' + lyr, 'ogr')
```

**Note** : The Dissolve algorithm pick the attributes of the first feature (of the original shapefile) and assigns it to the feature of the dissolved shapefile, automatically.

Comment: That worked beautifully! Thanks!